# MySQL - group by criterion AND count # of items that are grouped together - how?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to execute 1 query that would select all items ("SELECT * FROM `t-shirts`), group them by certain criterion ("GROUP BY `style`, `color`") but at the same time count the # of UNIQUE 'color' items that were grouped together? I can do that by cycling through each style->color and count the number of items, but I thought that perhaps there's an easier way of doing that.

Thanks.

P.S. Solved: remove `color` from GROUP BY, and used "COUNT (distinct color)":

```
SELECT *, COUNT (distinct color) FROM t-shirts GROUP BY style
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(`field`), `style` FROM `t-shirts` GROUP BY `style`
```

Where `field` is the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT style, COUNT(*) FROM t-shirts GROUP BY style`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT style, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM `t-shirts` 
GROUP BY style
```

Answer (score 1):

Count is a group function, and can be used with a select * as well:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`field`) FROM `t-shirts` GROUP BY `style`
```